# Is it possible to define a constant in app.php and use it in filesystems.php in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, include

I want to define some of my configuration in one file.
I want to put in `config/app.php` `define("PATH", "path/to/uploaded/files");`
   and use it in `config/filesystems`

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => PATH,
],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea to put this data into `app.php` and then use it in `filesystems.php`. You should add PATH to the [`.env` file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration), because PATH will be different for each machine:

```
PATH=path/to/uploaded/files
```

And then use this variable in the `filesystems.php`:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => env('PATH'),
],
```

Comment: I know it will change form machine to machine ,i appreciate your solution  but you can change your path in constant variable that you already declared when you move to another machine. Your solution provides the same thing, and it does't make any difference from using const.

Comment: @wahdan and what if you'll work in a team? Or the path will be different on your machine and server? How would you use VCS then?

Comment: Currently i am working with a team and we are using git , each one of us have to change the path based on his machine because the folder is local not shared between us ,when we deploy to the server we just change the path and everything  works as expected .

Comment: So, each of you change the `app.php` after each pull? Tens times a day?

Comment: nope we have two files called app.php and app.example.php, and we put app.php to .gitignore .when someone want to add something in app.php he will just add it in app.example.php and push the file.With this way none of us will need to change the const PATH. You will see there is .env and .env.exmaple , i know but i want it in app.php

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel and you're doing a terrible thing. If you want to do it right, just use `.env` file for that.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can , in your config/filesystems just include /config/app.php, then you can use variables defied in config/app.php like they are in config/filesystems.

Comment: the problem is when i did that this message appear
PHP Notice:  Constant PATH already defined in /var/www/html/laravel/config/app.php on line 3

Comment: That's becaule in each of your two files, there is a constant PATH. You may just remove one from config/filesystems.

Comment: i added ` define("PATH", "path/to/uploaded/files")` in app.php, in filesystems i added `include ('app.php');` and i put PATH in root key like this :

   `'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => PATH,
        ],`

still the same message.